# Replace value in dictionary by matching another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```python
dict_A = {
    'Key A': Value1,
    'Key B': Value2
}

dict_B = {
    Value1: ValueX,
    Value2: ValueY
}
```

How can I replace  values in dict_A by a value from dict_B when value-key are matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict_A = {k: dict_B.get(v, v) for k, v in dict_A.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get()`:

```py
dict_A = {"Key A": "Value1", "Key B": "Value2"}

dict_B = {"Value1": "ValueX", "Value2": "ValueY"}

for key, value in dict_A.items():
    dict_A[key] = dict_B.get(value, value)

print(dict_A)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Key A': 'ValueX', 'Key B': 'ValueY'}
```